# VNC Open Source For iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, vnc

Is there any open source code available for VNC client for the iOS platform?

Answer (score 0):

This Open Source package called `wdaproxy` provides an web application that is able to be used to remote control any iOS device with the WebDriverAgent (by Facebook) installed.
https://github.com/openatx/wdaproxy

Found this casually on the testerhome forum that has a ton of Chinese users, it provides a partial remote controlling of the phone through the browser session and is the nearest non-jailbreak option found so far.